# Problem with grep command

Tags: grep, prompt

I have three files `testx`,`testy` and `testz` all in same directory `Sikh`. All three files contain same data or content. The contents are:

```
aaabb  Aaaaa  AAAAA 

bbbcc  Bbbbb  BBBBB

ff–ff  Ccccc  CCCCC 

cccdd  Ddddd  DDDDD
```

Now I want to display the text containing `A` in all three files. What I have done so far is:

```
 grep '^A'*
```

But it does not display anything. So can anyone help me sort this out.

Comment: `grep ^A` will show you lines starting with A

Comment: Is my command wrong then? or what output do you except from my command.

Comment: `grep --no-filename A test?` seems to work fine. Just loose the `^` (which means *at the beginning of a line*) and optionally add a `-h` or `--no-filename` to supporess printing the filenames in front of the pattern).  Note that `test?` will match textx, testy and testz, but that `*` is also quite valid here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't show anything, because your Text has no ^A in it.

The ^ means "Beginning of line". And you have no line that begins with a Capital A.

You could search with:

```
grep "A" *
```

This will find the AAAAA in your first Line.

Or search for example:

```
grep "^a"
```

That finds the aaabb line in your text.

Grep is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to display lines containing "A" in the 3 files, try this command:

```
cat testx testy testz | grep A
```

sure, if you are in "Sikh" directory

Comment: I can display it but I have a question in my exam where I have to give this command. But when I try it, it displays nothing. So is the question wrong or have I done something wrong.

Comment: yup unfortunately your command was wrong :/